# How to structure index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have users index and blogs index. Now I want to enable users to create posts on by blog.

My first thought is that this is how my index should look like:

```
{
  "title": "Blog post title",
  "content": "Post text",
  "user": {
    "username": "lala",
    "name": "Johnny",
    "birthday": "1991-29-12"
  }
}
```

Which looks good. But what if user changes his name and birthday. Then I need to go through all blog posts and update "user" object?

What if that needs to happen with multiple indexes?

How should I store data like this?

Comment: That's a good structure, i.e. denormalizing your data is the way to go with ES. If you ever need to update many documents at once, the [update by query endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) will be your friend.